# Domain/IP address blacklisted

Tags: seo, facebook, social-media, blacklist, instagram

I started a website last year and did not realise that the mail server was enabled.  As a result the domain has been responding to `EHLO`/`HELO` requests with `localhost.localdomain` which Composite Blocking List (https://www.abuseat.org/) (CBL) considers a spam IP address indicator, thus, my site's IP address has been blacklisted.

I have fixed the issue, disabled mail server as it is not needed, and self-removed the IP address from the blacklist.  But I cannot post Instagram or Facebook posts using the domain - it is blocked as going against community standards. I do not know what effect this has had on SEO.

Can anyone give me an indication as to how long it will take for Instagram, Facebook, Google and other social platforms to synchronize with CBL to lift the ban on links?

Also, has anyone had a similar experience which gives an indication as to how long it will take for the domain to recover trust that may have been lost with the likes of Google, Instagram and Facebook?